# Java Insert a string after 2nd paragraph

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and this is what I'm trying to do:
I have a String content which is a string with html tags

```
    <p><strong>First Paragraph</strong></p>
    <p><i>Second paragraph....</i></p>
    <a>....more tags etc...
```

There are several paragraphs with other html tags in between. I'm trying to insert a link after the 2nd paragraph.

I tried with string.split but it's not really working.

```
 String str = content;
 String[] temp;
 String delimiter = "[<p>]+";
 temp = str.split(delimiter);
 for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
 System.out.println(temp[i]);
```

Any ideas on how to do this?
thanks

Comment: Where do you want to insert it? inside the second string? a new index (cant be done)?

Answer (score 0):

Your insertion point should be idx = str.indexOf("</p>",str.indexOf("</p>") + 1) + "</p>".length();

Then you can do

String newStr = str.substring(0,idx) + lineToAdd + str.substring(idx);

Answer (score 0):

If that what you work with is XHTML, then you can treat that document as XML and use one of the available Java interfaces to work with the document.

This, however, could be to much machinery if your task is only that simple as you've described. If you plan to do more complex modifications you can try to use more involved methods, otherwise use @user1291492 idea.